# Django | No muestra imágenes

Tags: django, django-models, django-urls

Guarda corréctamente las imágenes en el directorio media/dispositivos, pero no muestra la imagen en pantalla. ¿Qué hago mal?

Directorio "media" está en la raíz.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Archivo** dispositivo_list.html

```
    {% for dispositivo in object_list %}
<img style="height:30px" src="{{ dispositivo.imagen_dispositivo.image.url }}">
    {% endfor %}
```

Devuelve:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Archivo** models.py

```
class ImagenDispositivo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Nombre',max_length=50)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='dispositivos/')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Imagen dispositivo'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Imagen de dispositivos'
        ordering = ['name']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Dispositivo(models.Model):
    imagen_dispositivo = models.ForeignKey(ImagenDispositivo, on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=False, blank=False)
    marca = models.CharField('Marca',max_length=50,null=True, blank=True)
    modelo = models.CharField('Modelo',max_length=50,null=True, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Dispositivo'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Dispositivos'
        ordering = ['instalacion']

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.pk)
```

**Archivo** settings>local.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media")
```

Archivo urls.py (general)

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, re_path, include
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('blog.urls')),
    path('dispositivo/', include('dispositivo.urls')),
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Comment: Seria así: `{{ dispositivo.imagen_dispositivo.image.url }}`

Comment: De esa manera inspeccionado el elemento muestra en la web que genera: /media/dispositivos/siemens-s7-1200.png Es decir, lo mustra bien en el código pero la imagen no se ve. Se ve el típico recuadro de imagen que no muestra imagen.

Comment: Que pasa si abres la URL de la imagen en una nueva ventana, aparece la imagen o da 404? puede que no este configurado para servir el contenido estatico de la carpeta `media`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Faltaba añadir en la urls.py general del proyecto:

```
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Answer (score 0):

Verifica que te entrega `{{ dispositivo.imagen_dispositivo.url }}` en el atributo, ya que el valor no es una URL absoluta.

`settings.MEDIA_URL` puede ayudarte a obtener la ruta completa (absoluta) de la imagen.

```
<img style="height:30px" src="{{settings.MEDIA_URL}}{{ dispositivo.imagen_dispositivo.url }}">
```

Comment: Parece que de esa manera tampoco funciona